RTK Query with createSelector
Trying to use createSelector with RTK Query
export const selectXX = createSelector(
  [
    (state: IRootState) => state.xx.A
    (state: IRootState) => state.xx.B,
  ],
  (A, B):IViewerSpace[] => {

    if (A == null || B == null) {
      return [];
    }

  const args = {
     A: A,
     B: B
  }
  const resp = designRTK.endpoints.getData.select(args);
  const abc = resp(state).data // state not available

  ...some transformationlogic

});

To fetch data I'm using endpoints.getData.select(args)
To access the data
const abc = resp(state).data // state not available
Problem is, the full state is not available when using createSelector.
How do I solve this?

Something like this may work:
export const selectXX = createSelector(
  [
    (state: IRootState) => state.xx.A
    (state: IRootState) => state.xx.B,
    (state: IRootState) => state, // <-- add input selector that returns entire state
  ],
  (A, B, state): IViewerSpace[] => {

    if (A == null || B == null) {
      return [];
    }

    const args = { A, B };

    const { data } = designRTK.endpoints.getData.select(args)(state);

    // ...some transformationlogic
  }
);

But using a selector function that just returns its input or just returns the entire state object could have negative effects and is not generally recommended. This implementation will likely re-run anytime the Redux state is updated.
There's a dependency on the selected/derived A and B state.
I suggest splitting up the logic to make the returned "A or B" selector value an additional argument passed to a second selector, the UI will need to call both.
Example:
const selectXX = (state: IRootState) => state.xx;

const selectXXA = createSelector(
  [selectXX],
  xx => xx.A,
);

const selectXXB = createSelector(
  [selectXX],
  xx => xx.B,
);

export const selectAandB = createSelector(
  [
    selectXXA,
    selectXXB,
  ],
  (A, B): IViewerSpace[] => ({ A, B }),
);

In the UI:
const aAndB = useSelector(selectAandB);
const selectXX = useMemo(() => designRTK.endpoints.getData.select(aAndB), [aAndB]);

const value = useSelector((state: IRootState) => {
  const { data } = selectXX(state);

  // ...some transformationlogic
});


The first approach makes createSelector useless as you pointed out, will trigger when anything changes in state. The second one maybe works but I don't think that how it's supposed to work. In comp it should be just one row. Here's an example from the docs https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-8-rtk-query-advanced but that one don't have any arguments.

@Joe First part, yes. Second part, can you link to a more specific section on that page, it's unclear which example you are referring to.

Oh sorry. Here it is https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-8-rtk-query-advanced#selecting-users-data

@Joe Ah, yeah, it's because you are passing a query argument that you need to create a memoized/stable query selector function. See  this endpoints.select example. The reason it's two selectors is because you need to select the "A or B" state first so it can be used as the query arg of the second selector.

We can modify the selector to access the state:
The base selector uses createSelector with RTK Query but leaves the actual data fetching to be done outside the selector.
I am using the selector, passing the state explicitly to fetch data using endpoints.getData.select(args).
Please find the code below:
import { createSelector } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { designRTK } from './yourApiSlice';

Create the base selector using createSelector with RTK Quer
export const selectXX = createSelector(
    [
        (state: IRootState) => state.xx.A,
        (state: IRootState) => state.xx.B,
    ],
    (A, B): IViewerSpace[] => {
        if (A == null || B == null) {
        return [];
        }
        return { A, B };  // Return the args object
    }
);

I use the selector and fetch data with the full state:
export const fetchDataWithTransformedLogic = (state: IRootState) => {
    // Get the computed A and B from the selector
    const { A, B } = selectXX(state);

    if (!A || !B) {
        return [];
    }

    // Fetch data using RTK Query's select method with the full state
    const resp = designRTK.endpoints.getData.select({ A, B })(state);

    // Check if data is available and proceed with transformation logic
    if (resp?.data) {
        const abc = resp.data;

        // const transformedData = ...

        return abc; // Or return transformedData
    }

    return [];  // Return empty array if no data is available
};

the full state to fetch data from RTK Query inside a separate function (fetchDataWithTransformedLogic)
